# How to configure VS Code to auto hide, not close, the Terminal panel after a task completes

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

After a task completes, the terminal will stay open. Is there anyway to auto hide it?

I am **not** talking about closing the window as described at https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_57#_automatically-close-task-terminals because that will remove all the output.

I only want to hide the Terminal so that I can still go back to the output if I need it by opening the Terminal panel.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hopefully there is a better way that I don't know of but this works.  Make these tasks in your `tasks.json`:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",

  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "echo and hide",
      "dependsOrder": "sequence",
      "dependsOn": [
        "simple echo",
        "hide terminal"
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "simple echo",
      "command": "echo I have been hidden",
      "type": "shell",
      "problemMatcher": []
    },
    {
      "label": "hide terminal",
      "command": "${command:workbench.action.togglePanel}",
      "type": "shell",
      "problemMatcher": []
    }
  ]
}
```

And you would run  the "echo and hide" task which would run the task you really want first and then run the task with the command `${command:workbench.action.togglePanel}` in it to hide the Panel (assuming that is where your Terminal is).

Unfortunately, what you can't do is this:

`"command": "echo 'I have been hidden' && ${command:workbench.action.togglePanel}"`

it doesn't seem to work.

---

Alternatively, look at the presentation properties:

```
    {
      "label": "simple echo",
      "command": "echo I have been hidden",
      "type": "shell",
      "problemMatcher": [],
      "presentation": {
        "echo": true,
        "reveal": "silent",    // <== open only on problems
        "focus": false,
        "panel": "shared",
        "showReuseMessage": true,
        "clear": false
      }
    }
```

This will not open the Terminal if it is closed (unless there are problems with the task).  But it will **not hide** a Terminal that is **already open** when you run the task.  If you want the Terminal to always hide when you run a task you may have to look at the first option of dependent tasks.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: With using the `presentation` option, is there a way to have some kind of alert/pop up that says the task is done?

Comment: I don't see any such option in the `presentation` options.  I think some people try to get a bell to sound when a task finishes.  You could search for that.